# gmp value into char*

Tags: c, gmp

I don't understand how I can get mpz_t type variable into char*. I've tried many functions, but my char* stays empty.

I can output my B variable:

```
mpz_t B;
gmp_printf("B: %Zx\n", B);
```

But how to convert that B variable into char*?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `mybuffer = mpz_get_str(NULL, /*base*/10, B);` does what you want. (It allocates the returned buffer. You can have it write to an existing buffer if you prefer - see the manual for how to compute the size required.)

Answer (score 0):

```
gmp_sprintf(array, "%Zx", B);
```

Comment: Note that this function is not recommended, since there is no protection against writing past the end of the buffer ( http://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Functions.html#Formatted-Output-Functions )